# Extracting Specific Variables from a | delimited .txt and extracting them to a new .txt

Tags: perl, extract, user-input, delimiter

I have a .txt that is say 100,000 rows (observations) by 50 columns (variables), and the variables are | delimited.  I would like to extract the 8th and 9th variables (or 7 and 8 if the indexing were to start at 0).  In doing so, I'd like to create a new .txt that is 100,000 rows (the same observations) by 2 columns (these 2 variables) in which these 2 variables remain | delimited.

For example, the data in one row is formatted as:

```
var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6|var7|var8|var9|var10|var11 .........
```

I'd like to create a .txt with this row being:

```
 var7|var8
```

I've tried:

```
 $ perl -wplaF'|' -e'$_ = join "|", @F[7, 8]' fileoriginal.txt > filenew.txt
```

This output is just kind of gibberish, however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `-F` is compiled into a regular expression, and `|` is a special character in regular expressions. To use a literal `|` char, you need to escape it on the command line.

One of

```
perl -F\\\| -wlape ...
perl -F'\|' -wlape ...
```

does the trick on Unix.

Comment: Thanks!  I use cygwin.  Do you mean: perl -F\\\| -wlape  -e'$_ = join "|", @F[7, 8]' fileoriginal.txt > filenew.txt ?

Comment: You don't want to use `e` twice (so either `-wlape '<code>'` or `-wlap -e '<code>'`, but yeah.

Comment: perl -F\\\| -wlap -e'$_ = join "|", @F[7, 8]' file1.txt > file2.txt
seems to work!!